# New good answers don't get enough attention (vote sorting algorithm)

Tags: feature-request, voting, upvotes, sorting

### Problem

One problem I see regularly, is that really good answers that are submitted a while after the initial question, have a very hard time rising to the top. Which is especially true if there are a lot of answers.

Of course this comes naturally, since people looking for quick fixes/answers are just sifting through the top answers, and of course upvote those that seem to be most helpful in their situation, while a really comprehensive or even more-correct answer might be hidden on page two.

### How could this be tackled?

One thing I could imagine to help this issue, would be an additional sort (tab) like [reddit's best comment sorting system.](http://www.redditblog.com/2009/10/reddits-new-comment-sorting-system.html) Which would be an algorithm that takes into account how much "attention" an answer has received / how many people have possibly seen it, and calculates this against the received votes. Of course this has to "make sense", and not simply allow a late answer with one or two upvotes to rise above a "well proven" answer that has been seen a lot. But overall it seems doable, at least imho. ^^

Comment: Reddit posts don't have much of a long-term access pattern. Stack Overflow posts *do*. Over time, good answers do rise up. Really, they do!

Comment: I think if people want to see late answers, they'll already be sorting by activity, or by newest and scrolling to the bottom.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Well looking at some of the questions with many ansers this does not seem to be the case. Furthermore the long-term access pattern of SO is exactly why it would make sense (to me at least). Following is probably not the best example since it is not quite an  opinion-free question, but still how would a late answer in a thread like this possibly raise to the top: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered

Comment: @Levit: That post is *locked*, noone can vote on answers there.

Comment: Unless a post is locked, late answers can still be voted up, and the existing sorting is sufficient as @BilltheLizard mentioned; if the community agrees that an answer is more thorough than another it naturally rises to the top.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: As I said "not the best example ..." just was looking for one of those questions with more than 10 answers because only very few people sift through more than that. Until that happens just once, the other mediocre answers - that already had a headstart - have been upvoted several times in the meantime.

Comment: @Levit: sure, but *over time* the better answer is upvoted *anyway*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters surely it would aid usability that the 'best' answer be sorted to the top...now...today!  Now, the 'best' answer doesn't not necessarily equate to the best answer 5 years ago (judged by upvotes) which has had a 5 year head start on a better more current answer given one month ago.  What I would like to see is something like a 'vote velocity' sort option, say votes per year average.

Comment: @ptutt: perhaps that is an idea. Have you fleshed that out into a feature request yet?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I thought this question was a feature request, that's why I voted it up? Are you saying I should add my own question with my own proposed algorithm? Here is a really good example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository of a question with an answer that is accepted and has most votes and yet it is not the best answer (even has a link to the best answer within itself).  Google is updating it's search algorithm all the time to keep the best results to the top.  If SO is to remain at the top of it's game it needs to do the same.

Comment: @ptutt: yes, I meant posting a new question.

Comment: Just put more weight in recent votes, for example by aging votes. The idea is not new. If I find time I will look for a possible duplicate target.

Comment: if voters and moderators do their job (voters vote down obsolete stuff & flag duplicates/non answers and vote good content up / moderators delete duplicates or link only) the noise is reduced and answers rise to the top, slowly. Sometimes it appears unfair that old 2008 answers have so many votes when they're obsolete. True but only voting will fix this. I upvoted this question, but IMHO this is going to be impossible/overcomplicated to implement something about it

Comment: Although it takes time, answers relying on newer language implementations will make it to a top position eventually. I agree that the current system can definitely be improved by adding an "age" factor to votes (or something). But I don't think it's necessary per se. Looking at my top answer to a question posted 10 years ago, it has garnered 19 votes since posting in April, bringing it to the fifth spot, which IMO is well within visibility range for anyone taking the time to find relevant answers I think people looking for "new implementations" already have their answers sorted by "active"

Comment: People will stop at whatever answer gets the job done. So it's not a big problem as this isn't codereview ,if an answer doesn't work they will scroll to one below it

Answer (score 8):

## Current sorting solutions are naive - there is no easy way to find the more relevant/actual answers.

Current sorting gives a huge advantage to answers that are posted early on in the game. An answer that gets more votes is sorted higher, and therefor has more chance of getting more votes. While this is essential, it also means that newer good answers aren't easy to find, and aren't likely to get the attention they deserve.

Imagine an 8 year old popular question with many answers. After a new feature has been introduced to a language, someone posts an answer with a new improved solution. As a user I would like a reasonable way to find such an answer.

Naturally at the beginning the answer will be somewhere on page 3 or 4. The thing is, even on the rare occasion that it is up-voted, as a user I can't prioritize such an up-vote over an up-vote that occurred 8 years ago. However:

1. Such a vote represents better quality, as it was earned for much less views.
2. The vote is more recent, and therefor might be more relevant technology rise.

The OP's solution makes sense, but might be more difficult to implement. I'd opt for an additional sorting tab that gives more value to more recent votes.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294637/feature-request-introduce-an-optional-sort-option-for-answers-that-lets-new-go?rq=1 is a feature request on the same lines that makes some valid points.

Comment: It is even [an official meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533) (FGITW).

Comment: Is there any way for someone on SOF to take a look at this and reply?

Comment: @BenCarp I don't think there's a structured mechanism for that (yet). They may or may not look at it. They may have already considered the feature-request, and decided to ignore it in favor of more important items.