# What to do if there is a better answer on an old high-upvoted question with many answers

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I see some old questions with high upvotes and lots of answers. At the bottom there are much better answers than the accepted answer or high upvoted answers.

Usually that answers has +500 upvotes, so how can we go up that better answers for visiters? Probably below than %1 see that answers and they don't even upvote, or even they does it doesn't affect since others usually has +500.

Comment: You can upvote it as first action and good answers will, over time, rise to the top. If it is a highly viewed and used canonical there might be a way to clean it up and maybe convert everything to CW, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: Much better answers for you or generally speaking? Cause technically OP accepts what worked best for him/her

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there's no good solution for this. It's practically impossible for a new answer to ["rise to the top"](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) when there are lots of answers with lots of upvotes. That's because most people look only at the top answers, so even if the new answer got some upvotes after some period of time, the top answer would probably get like three times more upvotes in the same period of time.

That's why I proposed to [add a way to sort answers based on recent votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320150/add-a-way-to-sort-answers-based-on-recent-votes). Unfortunately, that proposal didn't get much attention or positive feedback.

In my opinion, the best solution is to ask and self-answer a new question, and close the old question as a duplicate of the new question. It may be a good idea to make that new question a Community Wiki, so you won't be accused of rep-whoring.