# How can recent answers catch up with popular old answers?

Tags: discussion

I have seen many old questions, which have been answered in the last 4  to 7 years and the top 3 answers have been written during that time.

I have seen some recent good answers, which are more useful than the top 3 answers. The old answers have become popular due to more views over a period of time.

I can provide some examples but don't want to pin-point a particular set of questions. You can look into top rated questions or frequently viewed questions to understand my problem statement.

It's surprising to see that good answers are not becoming as popular as old answers. Is this trend to continue as it is?

**Edit**: Adding a bounty does not seem to be right option after few tests with this option. The loss in reputation may or may not be compensated by up-votes to your answers even though they are best answers.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267018/promoting-new-answers-to-old-questions

Comment: I know there was a request to either change the sort algo or give us another tab that ranks answers by recent votes.  The goal is to basically suppress older votes(by not weighting them the same amount)  so newer answers can be ranked with the legacy highly voted answers.

Comment: Well, it will generally take at least 4-7 years for such answers to catch up.  Probably longer, Google doesn't like SO as much as it used to and now favors primary sources.  As well it should, Q+A is pretty shoddy lately and the site is filled with link traps to old content, added by SO users that didn't research their question.  Or the question subject simply gets outmoded by the average ~7 year change-everything-you-do software life cycle.  The answers will still be around 25 years from now, time aplenty.

Comment: I have had several of my new answers to old questions catch up and even in some cases eventually accepted. It just takes a long-time. It has been my experience that excellent new answers to old questions will usually gather more upvotes over time and can in many cases catch up. Sometimes bounties can help.

Comment: I agree that there's a problem. Many times I bump into old answers and sometimes it takes me a while to  realize that something better is present below. Maybe we could solve it by making old votes go stale? Or simply increase the value of new votes for the sorting algorithm.

Comment: Related: [Add a way to sort answers based on recent votes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320150/add-a-way-to-sort-answers-based-on-recent-votes).

Comment: My top rated answer has over 1,000 votes and was given 3 and a half years after the question was asked, when at the time an answer with 300 votes was already present. My answer gained traction because I started linking directly to it when voting to close similar questions. I believe a lot of really good, under-appreciated answers are simply in that state because not all that many people know they exist. If you want an answer to be seen, sometimes you just need to find an audience to share it with.

Comment: Can you show some specific examples of this please?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly *sometimes you just need to find an audience to share it with* How would you do that?

Answer (score 58):

This is definitely something which has been discussed before, and that in general the community is aware of.

It can take years to gain traction sometimes (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16025232/1026459) and even then you will never catch up to the old popular answer. This has been a problem for a long time and there haven't been many general solutions.

Personally I would appreciate a tab that sorted answers based on their "hotness" score. The [formula is described at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/178816) as

```
(MIN(AnswerCount, 10) * QScore) / 5 + AnswerScore
-------------------------------------------------
         MAX(QAgeInHours + 1, 6) ^ 1.4
```

It would be nice to see it as a tab option like this

[image]

Comment: Some related threads: - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263573/create-a-new-answer-order-that-considers-vote-count-how-old-it-is-and-answer-c
- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125455/sorting-new-answers-to-old-questions?rq=1
- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6662/how-to-give-some-boost-to-some-really-good-answers-that-arrive-late?rq=1
- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15805/how-can-we-make-good-answers-to-old-questions-float-to-the-top
- http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267018/promoting-new-answers-to-old-questions Good keyword: recommender systems

Comment: Rather than just the age of the answer, I would instead prefer the age of the votes to be taken into consideration, with more weight for more recent votes.

Comment: is your request has been approved by SE as feature request?

Comment: @Ravindrababu - That isn't really how it works. They see all of the stuff posted on meta, but as far as implementation goes it requires more internal discussion and agreement. While some features may seem "nice to have" it is up to the team if they are "need to have" and that doesn't happen overnight (usually). Also, there is the small issue with sorting votes with regards to age in that you need to have the whole set of votes instead of just a count, and that can be a performance consideration. All in all, it could be some time, or never, before this is considered as a feature by SE.

Comment: I would agree with this if the 'hot' tab/sorting was default. Provided the algorithm was favorable

Comment: I've been using StackOverflow for years and have never once noticed that "active, oldest, votes" UI.

Answer (score 27):

Even without changing the votes on an answer, the *sorting* of answers could reflect a weighting of favoring recent votes over old ones.

An answer with 10 recent up votes is certainly a more worthy one with 10 votes from years ago.

As answers near the top certainly enjoy reviewers primary consideration, this would allow tending new answers to rise quicker to the top of the heap.

---

[Edit] On review, this has similarities to [@Travis J](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324428/2410359) although I would "age" answers over a longer time (e.g. months).

Comment: Incidentally I rarely upvote the top question due to this effect.

Comment: Stackoverflow should definitely introduce hot answer sorting and make it the default option to supply peoply with good quality answers quickly (isn't that the goal of Stackoverflow). Otherwise it just becomes way to tedious to sift through, understand and evaluate all the answers from years back (that might have been the best anwser back then but aren't any more) to find the best answer for today. This problem will only get worse over time. Just show me the answer ranked by the amout of upvotes they received in the last 12 month.

Answer (score 8):

## Adding a Bounty

*Premise:* Adding a bounty to an old question with a new answer can help it rise to the top faster.

This is a test rather than a definitive answer. I am trying it based on the advice in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267020/3681880). My test question that I have added the bounty to is here:

[How can I deploy an iPhone application from Xcode to a real iPhone device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-real-iphone-device)

## Notes

- I often add answers to old questions. Most of them are not worthy of bounty help, though, because the old answers are not outdated, just not as thorough as they could be. My new answers eventually do rise to the top (if they are significantly better than the other answers); it just takes a long time.
- My [test answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33928777/3681880) is starting with 14 votes. Check back in a week to see if the bounty (and meta effect) made a difference. The current top voted answer has 88 votes.
- Self promotion seems [a little dubious](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326616/is-it-acceptable-to-use-the-custom-message-on-a-bounty-to-promote-a-specific-ans), but in the end it is still in the best interest of the general visitor to have the most up-to-date answer at the top.
- It requires a minimum bounty of 100 to promote your own answer.

## Results of my test

Accepted answer (outdated): 50 votes -> 54 votes
Top voted answer (outdated): 88 votes -> 90 votes
My new answer: 14 votes -> 29 votes

A week of bounty lessened the distance between my up-to-date answer and the outdated top voted answer. However, it didn't change the display order of any answers.

So was it worth it? Yes, but marginally. It didn't cost me any rep (a modest net gain). And it probably cut a few months off the time it will take to pass the outdated second answer.

Changing the system to something like what Travis J recommended would probably be more effective.

Comment: Can I award bounty to my own answer?

Comment: @Ravindrababu: No. Your answer can benefit from better visibility plus a bounty message, though.

Comment: At the end of the week, since I can't add the bounty to my own answer, I guess it (or at least half of it) will go to one of those outdated answers...which is somewhat counter productive.

Comment: @Suragch: An answer added before the bounty started is not eligible for auto-awarding. If you don't manually award to a bad answer, none of the bad answers will get the bounty at all.

Comment: I thought that system will award bounty to top rated answer but I have realised that it won't happen in self bounty cases. With - in hours I requested moderator to remove bounty but they declined. I may lose bounty on this question

Comment: @Ravindrababu, yes, once you set a bounty you can't get it back. That is the reason I think they make the minimum 100 instead of 50 so that people won't just use bounties to get more points.

Comment: One more observation:  this question has received more attention in last three days only towards end of the bounty period.

Comment: @Ravindrababu, It usually happens that way because the question appears higher on the list and more people see it.

Comment: In my case, only my answer got 13 up votes and second best answer got 0 up votes for this bounty period.

Comment: I have posted one more question : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326015/starting-bounty-on-old-protected-question-by-community-user-where-answers-are-o : I am suggesting community user to start bounty for protected questions

Comment: I did not achieve require success with my bounty on the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777989/how-should-i-have-explained-the-difference-between-an-interface-and-an-abstract. Before bounty: order is : 190 56 40 18 10 6  ( 6 is mine). After bounty: 199 62 49 24 12 12 (12 is mine now).  Gains of top 6 answers: 9 6 9 6 2 6 ( mine). Surprisingly my answer is up-to-date with latest java features but   still it did not push-up the rating

Comment: @Ravindrababu. Yes, I'm thinking that a bounty is not all that useful. It hasn't helped at all so far for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37893345/3681880).

Answer (score -2):

Quora has a [more nuanced algorithm](https://www.quora.com/How-does-the-ranking-of-answers-on-Quora-work) for ranking answers:

> - upvotes and downvotes on the answer, in part based on how trustworthy voters are in a given topic
> - the previous answers written by the author
> - whether the author is an expert in the subject
> - the contents of the answer, including the type and quality of content (words, photos, links)
> - other signals, including ones that help us prevent gaming of ranking through votes

I've also read at some point that they adopted a slight randomization algorithm to give newer and unvoted answers a chance among the existing highly-upvoted ones.

Whatever you do, don't ask for votes for your answer, even if you genuinely believe it does deserve the votes and ask for them only if the voter also believes so. I've learned that [the hard way](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334484/downvoted-and-censored-after-asking-for-feedback-in-the-chat).

Answer (score -3):

Something you can do, at least for link-only old answers, is flag as NAA. (Of course, it's likely to require moderator attention before it's deleted.)

Of course this will not apply to most answers.

---

Also: No you may not award the bounty to yourself.

Answer (score -5):

In a few cases, I've written a better answer to an old question and had the OP accept my answer (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35270026/224132) about SSE horizontal sums).  This is the ideal case, but doesn't happen with abandoned questions.

---

Downvote old answers for being less-good than the new answers, even if they wouldn't warrant a downvote if the new answer wasn't there at all.

Leave a comment describing the situation under the question, or the accepted answer.  If there are already a huge amount of comments on one, leave your comment in the other place so it's visible.  Consider using **bold** in your comment, but only if there's something seriously wrong with the old answers.

---

### If there's a real problem with an old answer (not just completeness / style)

i.e. if it's now a bad idea, not just sub-optimal or less well written / complete:

Consider leaving an edit at the top of the old answer with a one-list summary of the situation.  Probably only if there is a serious problem with an old answer (caused by changes to the language or something, but maybe even if the problem existed even when it was first posted.)

Don't vandalize old answers if they still work and there wouldn't be anything wrong with following their suggestion today.

I'm imagining a line like:

---

This answer is no longer appropriate for foobar version 13 or later, see @somebody's answer

---

Use a `---` horizontal ruler to separate edits like that from the main body of the old answer.

You can take time to say what's wrong in a comment, or in the other answer, but don't insert a whole paragraph.  Inserting "this answer sucks" text into existing answers is questionable at best.

Ideally, the user that posted the answer is still active, and will notice your edit and rewrite their answer to update it, or even delete it if it has no value compared to the other answer.

Comment: Why on earth should we downvote perfectly good answers just because another answer is better?

Comment: @DavidG: Downvote for not being good *enough*.  I'm imagining an answer that's better than nothing, but doesn't go into detail, or is really short.  Or has a solution that's only optimal in some cases.  It's part of curating / maintaining the site.

Comment: If an answer is "good" for any reason, even if it doesn't have all the required info (and doesn't contain anything bad), then I cannot imagine a situation where it would deserve a downvote. It may be that it doesn't get an upvote, but remember that the tooltip for downvote says `This answer is not useful`.

Comment: @DavidG: Yes, I'm suggesting we vote differently on old questions with overrated old answers.  It's not an obviously-great idea, but it's the first thing I thought of so I wrote it down and posted it to see what other people thought.  It's probably not a good idea when the overrated old answer doesn't really have anything wrong with it, except being not quite as good.  So I think I have to agree, I don't want to downvote "perfectly good" answers, only ones with at least some kind of flaw (which might include lack of explanation for a simple how do I `<x>`).

Comment: Downvotes should really be saved for answers that are incorrect or downright dangerous.

Comment: How people vote is their prerogative. One of the valid ways to vote is to downvote competing answers; this is simply because of the way Stack Overflow is designed for gamification. The best answer should rise to the top, by way of voting. The strategies employed on that are up to each individual user, provided each user only votes once (ie doesn't engage in voting fraud).

Comment: @DavidG Upvoting a better answer and downvoting a higher placed answer immediately doubles your impact. It sounds wrong but since voting is free you cannot forbid it anyway.

Comment: @Trilarion I know why people are doing it, I just don't agree with the reasoning.

Answer (score -8):

I don't really see this as a problem.  If you are concerned that better answers are buried, comment on the top answer to invite the poster to improve it, or improve it yourself with an edit - avoiding edit wars, of course.  That way the top answer is improved and visitors can see the best answer at the top right away rather than waiting years for it to percolate up.

I mean, you did care more about making the site as useful as possible, rather than just about getting reputation credit for the best answer, right?

Comment: Isn't it bad form to attempt to modify another user's answer completely? We're talking about a different, better, answer. Not an improvement.

Comment: @ThomasBoby To me, the question is talking about a situation where the existing top answer is already good, so we would be talking about an improvement, not a "different" answer.  If the existing answer is actually wrong, that's a different situation and a downvote would be called for.