# Starting bounty on old protected question by community user, where answers are out of date

Tags: discussion, support

Answers for some of protected questions are out-dated with recent developments in programming languages (e.g. java)

Currently starting a bounty (which causes reputation loss to bounty initiator) is way to address this issue.

e.g. : [How should I have explained the difference between an Interface and an Abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777989/how-should-i-have-explained-the-difference-between-an-interface-and-an-abstract)

Since SOF website already maintains a bank of protected questions, it would be good idea to start bounty on these out-dated posts through "***Community***" user rather than individuals.

**EDIT:**

Reasons to start bounty:

1. Get the old answers reflected with latest developments
2. Get new answers for these protected questions, which are very old

One proposed solution: Interested people can start self bounty.

Drawbacks with this solution:

People like me can start bounty, but they lose reputation and even if their answer is best answer, they won't get bounty amount due to current rules. So it's unfair for people starting bounty.

e.g. [Does the Bridge Pattern decouples an abstraction from implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35079629/the-bridgepattern-decouples-an-abstraction/35079826#35079826)

My post is top rated and I can't get bounty since I have started bounty.

@downvoters : Understand the problem correctly.

This is follow-up to below SE question:

[How can recent answers catch up with popular old answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324384/how-can-recent-answers-catch-up-with-popular-old-answers)

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here. You want the community bot to take it upon itself to raise a bounty?

Comment: Yes. At least for protected questions.

Comment: How would such a system determine which questions have out-of-date answers? Why can't individuals still apply bounties if they're interested in it? Questions are "protected" because they've attracted a number of low-quality contributions (spam, none-answers, etc), not because they have more value than other not-protected questions.

Comment: @TZHX: I think this is sufficiently categorical a reason not to implement this that you should write an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: But you already added an answer with the Java 8 information.  So you're asking for someone to add an answer that matches yours so you can award them 100 of your rep? I'm confused.

Comment: If "community" raises a bounty then who exactly is going to award the bounty?

Comment: Top rated answer will get.

Comment: If I start bounty, I simply lose reputation even my answer is top-rated.

Comment: TheB, I would like to have old answers to be modified by respective authors and get new answers from others

Comment: Nathan Tuggy, If I start bounty, I lose reputation even if my answer is top rated by others. Due to this limitation, people may not be willing to start bounty

Comment: If you're not willing to pay then the information is not sufficiently valuable enough to you. That's the market for you. Awarding free bounties all over the place would devalue the rep and bounty system.

Comment: SO is **not** a source of truth - despite the fact some think it is. If you visit some tech sites with old, outdated articles you get a warning. On SO you are on your own. If you you can't fix it, and if "the market" cannot fix it, let it rot. Sad, but true.

Answer (score 3):

Your reasoning seems to be:

1. Old answers may need updating.
2. A bounty may attract people who will post updated answers.
3. But you don't want to spend reputation on said bounties.
4. So the system should find posts that need updating, and post bounties on them.

Disregarding the third point, the fourth is simply impossible to implement. The system can't decide which answers are outdated, and if you introduce some kind of "Outdated, request bounty" button, then users are going to abuse it to get bounties towards their answers.

So without even wanting to dive into the potential benefits of this proposal, I'd vote against this based on that: not trivial to implement, open to abuse.

Just so you understand this reasoning, this is what I expect of a feature request:

1. Problem description. What problem do we currently have? *Is* it a problem? How is it a problem? What are the causes of this problem? Which facts support the problem description?
2. Possible workarounds. Which are there? Why do they not suffice?
3. Your solution(s) to the problem. How will they address the problem? What new risks do the solutions introduce? Will the benefits outweigh the drawbacks? How to implement them?

All of that seems to be missing, and hence I (and presumably the other downvoters as well) have interpreted your question as *"I want up-to-date answers, but don't want to spend reputation on bounties to get them updated"*. That's fine, but in my opinion that doesn't really warrant this feature request.

Apart from that, it seems like you're just looking for the Q&A titled [Interface with default methods vs Abstract class in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998454/interface-with-default-methods-vs-abstract-class-in-java-8).

If not, you may want to be a bit more specific in your bounty message than *"The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes"*. If you could have elaborated on what exactly you mean by "recent changes", you might have gotten a better chance at getting the answer you're looking for.