# Is it acceptable to use the custom message on a bounty to promote a specific answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, bounty

I recently found a bounty question with this custom message:

> The current answers do not contain enough detail.
>
> Although this question had many answers already, I
>   didn't feel that any of them provided enough detail to get a first
>   time user started easily. Therefore I added the answer below, titled
>   Simple Self-Contained Example (https://stackoverflow.com/a/path/to/answer). I
>   am adding a bounty now to help that answer become somewhat less
>   buried. If you think it deserves to be higher on the list, please help
>   it along. Or if you think you can add a better answer, then please do.
>   The question-to-answer vote ratio here shows that this question needs
>   some better answers.

Is it acceptable use the custom message portion of a bounty notice to promote the bounty adder's own answer?  To me, bounties should be used to promote existing answers, not new ones answered by the bounty awarder.  I don't think this is appropriate use of the custom message field.

Comment: They'll have at least no additional reputation gain (regarding the bounty points given away) from that action, if that is your concern.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not concerned about rep gain, but wondering if this is abuse of the "custom message" section of the bounty.  If the answer is "users can spend their repo however they want," that's fine.  This is just the first time I've seen someone try to promote one of their answers in a bounty message.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ unless visitors follow the hint on the post notice and instead of answering the question go and upvote the answer

Comment: @rene Well, I mentioned that in my answer now. Though I can't smell anything suspicious here. It's at the risk of the bounty owner to give away their rep for nothing regained.

Comment: Seems kind of slimy, but not against any rules. Kind of like scalping tickets; not necessarily against the law, but kinda risky.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it feels somewhat similar as comments along the line of *don't down vote my answser* `---` *please upvote my posts* `---` *let me know if you upvote, I'll return the favor*

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan right, that's why I'm trying to get a community or mod consensus.

Comment: @rene Well, but the latter come with no cost at all. Both are silly actions after all, and just thrown right back in the face of the beholder.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Yes, but those comments would also get flagged. I think JAL wants to know if this is something warranting an action by the community or mods.

Comment: @BSMP Depends on the professionalism of the comments. Downvotes are out of that anyways.

Comment: I've done this on several occasions, where I had a new and better answer buried deep to a very-old thread, and it would take years for my answer to catch up. At least in those cases, I think it's clearly to the site's benefit. **This is rarely worth the reputation it costs, so it won't attract much abuse from that angle.** I don't think this risk of abuse is very high. Unless you can make a case for why your answer is better, people are likely to ignore your message. Other answers can also get increased votes from the bounty attention, so your advantage isn't very large -- this can backfire.

Comment: Recently, I discovered someone's answer to a question thanks to their bounty that was used to promote it. If it wasn't for their bounty, I probably wouldn't have caught them red-handed plagiarizing from one of my own answers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Seeing that I am the one who posted the bounty, I will also add an answer/explanation here.

Although I was previously aware of the minimum 100 rep for posting a bounty on a question that already has one's own answer, I never thought of actually doing it until I read [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267020/3681880) (also referred to by [computerfreaker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326774/3681880)). I decided to try it as an experiment to see if it was a viable option for moving a new updated answer to the top of the list populated by obsolete answers (a real problem for old Stack Overflow questions). I wrote about that experiment [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324455/3681880). Long story short, it was only mildly successful (ie, it probably cut a few months of time off overtaking the obsolete answer above it).

The particular bounty referred to in the question here was my second time to try it. This time I did it not because the other answers were obsolete but because they were (in my opinion) inadequate. Although I am biased, of course, I genuinely believe [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37893345/3681880) is better than the existing answers. I added the bounty not for any short term rep gain (the 100 rep min is already a good deterrent for that), but to escape the sea of answers at the bottom of the list.

I agree with [πάντα ῥεῖ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326618/3681880) that self promoting an answer is "a bit narcissistic and silly" and I feel "a bit narcissistic and silly". However, I believe it is also in the interest of the community to have the best answers at the top. A new answer to an old question won't get upvoted and make it to the top (with or without a bounty) if it isn't significantly better than the old answers.

If the community feels like this is inappropriate behavior, I am happy to refrain in the future.

Answer (score 15):

Let me be sure that I have the scenario straight:

- A user has posted an answer to a question
- Said answer is buried underneath other answers
- User now wishes to promote their answer by offering a bounty on it
- User has *also* added text to indicate that this is the case

Before I get into this, let me assure you that bounties can be used to [award existing answers too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work), however there is an explicit proviso for self-awarded bounties.

> **Can I award a bounty to my own answer?**
>
> No. This used to be possible, but it has been disabled. The user would not get the reputation back, and the bounty will be displayed as +0, “this answer has been awarded bounty worth 0 reputation”.

The only question that raises is if awarding the bounty to the answer will actually boost the visibility of the answer, and my gut tells me "no".  What it *will* do, though, is draw more attention to the question and, subsequently, draw attention to the plug being made to it.

Personally, I'm not okay with using bounties in that way since at *best* it accomplishes *nothing*, and at *worst* it gives a bounty offerer a chance to put their own answer on one of the biggest loudspeakers we have here.  If I were to happen across a bounty like that, I'd likely flag it for moderator attention since it can't accomplish the purpose it's meant to.

Comment: _"If I were to happen across a bounty like that, I'd likely flag it for moderator attention  ..."_ Does that really need to blow the big shofar? Isn't such silly stuff self solving by the attracted community actions?

Comment: What's the difference between asking for an upvote in a comment and asking for an upvote in a bounty request, @πάνταῥεῖ?  Neither are acceptable behavior, but the bounty request is *worse* since it's *much* more noticeable.  Also, since users can't moderate bounties, the only demographic capable of helping us out would be moderators.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and flag the bounty question and let you know what happens.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I don’t see the problem. Bounties are meant to draw attention to a question and the user has to sacrifice reputation points for it which (s)he never gets back. If a user advertises his/her own answer, it might help or backfire, depending on the actual quality of the answer (and whether it actually adds something to the question not addressed by other answers). Readers usually react very sensible to loud self-advertising, so you better have a very good reason/answer, otherwise, the problem will become community solved very soon, without any moderator intervention.

Comment: @Makoto: Does that mean you're opposed to the "Reward existing answer" bounty reason?

Comment: FWIW @JAL another moderator marked your flag as helpful but none of us see the problem here. Pretty much what Holger said.

Comment: @BoltClock My issue with this is that we have had enough cases of bad things being up voted because of bounties that questions with bounties have been removed as audit cases.  Doesn't that mean that the community may not actually be voting correctly because of the "bounty effect"?  It may be that the reward out weighs the risk because people just assume it is good.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Doesn't that happen regardless of the motivation for the bounty anyway?

Comment: @BoltClock Yes but if the motivation is to advertise your answer and get votes it almost seems like there may not be a down side.  I would hope people down vote a bad answer but that doesn't seem to happen a lot unless it is really bad.

Comment: @BoltClock:  I should be explicit.  I'm fine with users awarding bounties on other answers.  I'm *not* fine with users asking others to look at their answer through the bounty system, since it feels similar to asking for upvotes on a comment, with the caveat that this is a much bigger type of comment.  I don't disagree that the user is spending their own reputation for this, but it still doesn't feel right with me.  As I said before, this is my opinion; if there's more official policy that I should be referring, please do point me towards it.

Comment: Maybe I'm just not seeing why it doesn't feel right to promote an answer to the question if it's OK to promote the question or reward an existing answer *directly* with a bounty that *is* awardable. It's not like readers aren't given a chance to look at the question and the rest of the answers before judging the answer that's being promoted specifically. And the only thing that makes promoting your answer in a comment "wrong" is that it's just plain unnecessary because a comment in itself does nothing but ping a specific user.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's important whether the answer being promoted is actually a *good* answer to an actually useful question, and you agree with the bounty-offerer that the question needs better answers.

Basically, **is the user making the site better in the long run**?  If so, I'd allow it at least in this one case, since there doesn't seem to be a clear rule against it (yet).  It sounds like a "wrong tool for the job" situation, in a case where there aren't better tools.  Promoting new good answers to old questions is a known problem on SO.

You didn't link the question, and I'm not keen enough to google the bounty text and find it myself.

---

However, IDK if this is something we'd want to see a lot of.  In popular tags, a small bounty could probably "pay for itself" by drawing attention and upvotes to a good answer.  Still, if they are good answers *to useful questions* and worthy of the attention, I think that's ok.

I think it will be pretty rare that people do this.  I think we only need to ban it if it starts making the site worse, with many vote-bait Q&As being promoted.  (i.e. promoting answers that aren't very special or much-needed, but still pay for the bounty due to unwarranted attention.)

I don't think this usage of a bounty should ever be suggested or promoted, but I think we should allow it on a case-by-case basis when it's used for a good cause.

Answer (score 6):

The top answer to [Promoting new answers to old questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267018/promoting-new-answers-to-old-questions?rq=1) (answer has 29 upvotes as of right now; the other answer on that question has just 7 votes) suggests doing exactly this.

> You can always add a bounty, there's even a fitting bounty reason:
>
> > **Current answers are outdated**
> >
> > The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.
>
> A bounty can often bring old question back, for example [Eclipse fails to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339841/eclipse-fails-to-start). You can always start a bounty, and then add your answer, or vice-versa.

Personally, I don't see anything wrong with this. The user is trading their reputation for higher visibility to their answer. That seems fair to me.

If the answer is good, it'll help more people and the user is likely to regain some of their reputation via upvotes. If the answer is bad, the user will likely be punished with downvotes and additional competition in the form of other answers may show up. It's a miniature meta effect the user has to pay for.

As far as the site health goes, even with answers sorting in random order, I believe visitors are likely to try solutions given in highly-upvoted and/or accepted answers before they try lower-voted answers. There's an implicit relationship between high upvote count and good quality. As such, if the new answer provides something the old answer didn't, or the old answer has become partially obsolete, I actually think it would make the site healthier for the new answer to start catching up in total upvotes.

Answer (score -2):

A bounty actually promotes a **question**, not a particular answer.

If the bounty is placed by one of the users, who answered the question the bounty points are given away from that user to attract more attention on the question.

Even if their answer will be accepted, they cannot regain these reputation points given away, if this should be your concern.

Though a question with an open bounty, might attract more views, and also more votes to that particular answer. *More votes* includes upvotes, and downvotes as well, so such behavior could cause a kind of unwanted *meta effect*.

But in the end there's nothing suspicious about doing such.

Given the bounty comment, it just looks like a bit narcissistic and silly action though. Fishy, but certainly not illegal here.

Comment: This doesn't address the point of using the "custom message" space to promote an answer.  If a bounty promotes a question, then that space should not be used to promote a particular answer.  Users should vote on the quality of the answer, not because someone asked them to.  I don't think this is appropriate behavior.

Comment: @JAL I don't think the _custom message_ makes much difference here. Bounty chasers aren't after about upvoting answers, but rather writing their own anyways.

Comment: I disagree.  I think that using the custom message as a sticky billboard on the question to promote a specific answer is wrong.  Just like asking for votes is wrong.

Comment: @JAL You might take the chance and vivisect the answer of that user in detail, maybe leave a downvote based on your results.

Comment: The quality of the answer is irrelevant to the question here.

Comment: @JAL _"asking for (up-)votes"_ is different from placing a bounty, no matter what comment was left there. It might quickly throwback on the actor if the answer along has arguable points.

Answer (score -3):

Many people here seem to be forgetting what should be the most important metric: Did the action make the site better or worse?

I see a lot of comments to the effect of "It's similar to asking for upvotes in comments, which is illegal." Maybe it is against the rules, but try to remember *the purpose of the rules themselves*. If there was an answer that was way awesome and perfect buried under a lot of trash (maybe obsolete answers, maybe just terrible answers, whatever), and it was imperative that the good answer be brought up from the bottom because people were missing it, what would you do if someone left a "This answer really needs to be at the top. Come on, let's +1"? That would be against the rules, but it would not be causing any problems; in fact, it would be in the site's best interests if it had a positive effect.

If this causes a lot of people to start breaking the rules and causes problems, then do something about it. Otherwise, if it is good for the site then leave it. Let that be your judge and flag accordingly.

There are probably some (many?) legalists here who would want my example "Come on, let's +1" comment deleted, but if the only reason for deleting it is "It's against the rules" and you ignore the benefit to the site then *you* are actually the one in the wrong for deleting it more than the person who made the comment. Don't cut off your nose to spite your face.

Comment: To the downvoters: please note that I never said whether the specific case of the original bounty but rather gave a generic recipe which may still result in a decision of flagging the bounty.

Comment: Also, I think it's pretty lousy to downvote an answer just because you may disagree with it. It is still a good answer even if you don't agree with the opinion. If you don't like opinions, get off meta.

Comment: And now my anecdote: If you disagree with this you are going to be the ruination of SO. Try remembering your disagreement when you're in a situation where you need to rely on this argument. "But officer, how can you still give me a ticket? If I didn't run that red light the jack-knifing truck lying on the ground next to my car would be _on top_ of it right now, and my kids and I would be dead instead of talking to you." "Officer: I don't care. It's against the rules to run the red light." You might not realize it when you're stuck inside the box, but strict legalism is very immature.

Comment: Now that it's a day later and this answer is still at -3 and no comments other than my own, I am going to point out the irony here. I have offered a great answer - in my opinion, the best answer. But now it will get less notice even though this message needs to be shouted from the rooftops.

Comment: Further irony: disagreeing with my answer is, in logical terms, automatically the wrong stance because it is self-contradicting. Hopefully the computer scientists here are familiar with a proof by contradiction of the sort: I want to prove that "a = b" and in this case I can do that by assuming that "a =/= b" (a does not equal b) and making a case that shows how this is impossible, therefor "a = b" is proven correct. By saying "the rules themselves are more important than the impact to the SO website" you are taking that negative, self-contradicting position.

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess and say that your answer is being downvoted because it doesn't even try to answer the question.  It argues for a framework for developing an answer... but it never applies it.  It also reminds people of certain people who tried to argue on Meta that the rules shouldn't be applied to them, without ever understanding the rationale for the rules.  Thus in the end, while your thesis of "the most important metric: Did the action make the site better or worse?" is correct, you've entirely missed the point that rules exist in response to harmful behavior.

Comment: Until you understand the reason for the particular rule, you cannot judge whether the post in question is part of the harmful behavior that the rule was designed to prevent.  It is not sufficient that a post (whether question, answer, comment, or bounty message) has some benefit, it is required that the benefit outweigh the harm.  And you only very briefly considered that harm was even possible and didn't fully explore it in your answer.  All that being a moot point, because this meta question asks whether there should be a rule against it -- it isn't currently breaking any.