# Is starting a bounty for self-promotion deemed OK?

Tags: discussion, bounty

This question is about whether any usage of bounty is good or you can abuse it. Particularly is it OK to start a bounty just to promote your own answers? There is a standard bounty goal of "Draw attention" but its description says "This *question* had not received enough attention" rather than "This *answer* had not received enough attention".

**Note**: The name of the particular user in the question is (post-factum) replaced with `SO_USER`. Obviously if you follow the links and/or read the comments here closely, you can easily deduce the name but remember that personality of the user is ***not*** the point here. This question is only about specific actions.

This question is inspired by two bounties started by one SO user recently on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45164645/separate-an-integer-into-two-addends) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925327/dynamically-filtering-a-pandas-dataframe) questions. Both questions have accepted and well upvoted answers that happen to be the same user who started the bounties. I engaged into a discussion under the first of the questions and although some of the comments have been removed, I have a screenshot that shows most of the history:

> [image: Discussion about the goal of the bounty]

IMHO it clearly shows that the sole purpose of those bounties by SO_USER is to draw attention to own answers. So my question is: is this kind of a bounty considered OK and I should apologize for taking it too personally? Or is this an abuse of bounties?

Note that this question doesn't have a `self-promotion` tag because it seems to be designated for self-promotion in some commercial interest and I'm not aware of any kind of commercial interests here.

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate of that post. The intent of that post appears to be genuine (bumping some answers that have more relevance over time). In OP's case, the intent appears to be "hey everyone look at my popular stuff and upvote".

Comment: @JacobH, although I did downvote there I'd ask anyone who find those questions here not to do so because as cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ rightly noted we should vote on the merits of the answer(s). So I think we generally should avoid downvoting at least until we have some general agreement on whether this is OK or bad behavior. Mass downvote of a good answers just because we don't like the person seems wrong.

Comment: Uber-meta dupe: [Is it OK to make a bounty to draw attention to my answer?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/234526)

Comment: I think having this discussion again for this specific case is fine. An extra factor is that the same user posting the bounty has protected the question (some time ago, though), prohibiting new users from answering it. Imo we should _never_ downvote for things not directly related to the post. If the answer is fine, but the users behaviour isn't, the response should not be to downvote.

Comment: @JacobH: Then combine it with: [What kind of bounty message is acceptable for promoting your own answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266231/2675154)

Comment: @JacobH: the community has discussed this before and no, they didn't think this is 'clear vote manipulation'.

Comment: The intent _is_ to have more people look at the question, that is what "draw attention to the question" bounty is for. Does it matter that I answered them? I feel the posts are quite useful and deserve to become more relevant on google search for people looking to find answers to questions like this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I guess I disagree with the community then. It's not the first time.

Comment: I don't think it is fair for you to be judge, jury, and executioner of the validity of a bounty just because you did not think the question was worth your time. The tone of this question certainly seems biased towards one side.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks... also, is there something we can do about the downvotes I've just received on my answers thanks to this inflammatory post?

Comment: Well, there are conflicting opinions.  [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326621/7296893) is the second most upvoted answer, and is against it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, I just want to re-iterate that I think those questions and answers are perfectly OK. I don't like the bounty because I can't imagine how it is worth time of any SO user. But I might be wrong here and that's why I started this meta question. P.S. And to re-iterate other point I still don't think that downvoting those answers from here is a good response.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth good point. This is effectively adding a bounty to ones answer AFTER you've answered the question. I don't know why people would think this adds anything to the site except noise, but apparently I'm in the minority.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth oops, that was genuinely oversight on my part. I've unprotected it now. Btw, that was my first protected question on the site ;-)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I'll note there that the context is _not_ the same. With that question, the user promoting their answer did not have the most upvotes or was accepted. The meta answer you linked to expressing concerns was against the bounty because that bounty would not be able to fulfil its purpose (i.e., boost that answer up). In my case, both my answers have been accepted and are at the top. I don't believe that answer applies here. I'm trying to boost the _entire post_ on Google search through increased views and votes, i.e., "bring attention", which is certainly a valid use for bounties.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I agree the situation is different. That's why I'm for discussing this again for your specific case, because I don't think there's community consensus about how to handle this situation. As for myself, I'm a bit indifferent as to wether we should allow it. It doesn't seem harmful to me. But apparently, others are against discussing this again.

Comment: @JacobH I'm sorry but I fail to see how it is "noise" to want to bump  naturally good Q&As up to become more relevant on google search. I'm positive these are problems people have on a day-to-day basis and I would like people to find them more easily. Again, does it matter that I've answered them? Does the fact that I've answered them automatically invalidate my opinion that the posts are good and deserve more visibility? The bounty system _allows_ for questions to be promoted for additional visibility, and _already has_ mechanisms in place to prevent abuse.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, do you have any evidence that such kind of a bounty in any way improves position in Google? Obviously good questions with good answers happen to have good Google position and attract bounties so there will be correlation. But I see no evidence for causation in this case. If you have some, I will be very interested.

Comment: @SergGr Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/) canonical Q&A from November. A gold standard question which did not receive much attention when it was first posted. After the bounty, it has become the first hit on google for "how to pivot a dataframe pandas". Similarly with [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49620538/timeline), another bounty of mine from a couple of months ago.

Comment: The timeline for [one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45925422/timeline), on which I've instated a bounty indicates it is a passive earner in its own right, and deserves more visibility.

Comment: I have awarded nearly 30 bounties to date, and have found that the majority of them (except for the ones belonging to the niche tags) have _all_ benefitted from the visibility.

Comment: Riddle me this, if you were interested in promoting the website (and not yourself) why have you only added bounties to your own posts?

Comment: @JacobH, that seems to be not true. cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ linked to questions where he awarded bounties to piRSquared's answers and unless they are clones (which doesn't look very plausible at the first glance) it means he did award bounties for others. My issue is different: looking at those time lines I don't see that bounty really improved anything. Upvotes rate seems steady over time both before and after bounties.

Comment: @JacobH I invite you to go through [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/c%E1%B4%8Fʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ?tab=bounties) and count the number of bounties that were awarded on content that wasn't mine (*Spoiler Alert*, it's greater than 0).

Comment: @JacobH Also, I never said I wasn't interested in promoting myself. In promoting the site and posts, I promote myself, that's just how it works and it cannot be helped. What I don't agree with is the claim that it is inappropriate, or "vote manipulation".

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: "*it cannot be helped*" Nonsense; it certainly *can* be helped. You could promote content that you're not directly involved with, and let others promote your content if they feel it deserves it. This is why the idea of "conflict of interest" exists; it recognizes that someone may not be acting in the best interests of the site, but instead for their own interests. A bounty from the person who asks the question makes sense. A bounty from someone answering it does not. All things being equal, this suggests some form of perfidy.

Comment: @NicolBolas When I said "it cannot be helped", it was with respect to the fact that serving one interest automatically served another. I have been _excessively_ open of my intentions to garner more votes and views. There is nothing underhand and deceitful about what I'm doing here, so I'd request you to read the entire discussion for context before casting aspersions.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'll also note that, of [all the bounties I've awarded (30 of them)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/c%E1%B4%8Fʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ?tab=bounties), a good number of them were not on my own questions or questions I'd answered.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Openly admitting to manipulating the system doesn't change the fact that it's a manipulation of the system. The bounty system is not meant to be a way to get questions higher on Google search. It's meant to be a way of drawing attention to questions that ***need answers*** (with a secondary purpose of rewarding quality answers). By using the system merely to promote answers, you're acting against this purpose.

Comment: @NicolBolas Bounties can be instated for drawing attention to a post—it's literally one of the reasons there—and not _necessarily_ to be answered; however I've mentioned that I would not mind if someone did answer it, I need to award the bounty to someone else at the end of the day. By the way, the bounty draws attention to not _just_ the answer, but the _question_ as well, a point that many seem to overlook. There are precisely systems in place that prevent this from being abused—I had to pay more to instate it than you, or anyone else would have. I think that seems fair.

Comment: @NicolBolas Another reason for instating bounties is to "reward an existing answer", and that reason implies that new answers to those questions are not required. Would you have preferred if I had instated the bounty for that reason? I _do_ think my answers are good and I wish for the post to become more visible. The fact that I answered them shouldn't invalidate my opinion that the posts are good and deserve more visibility. Of course, the interest looks to be self serving, and I was prepared for that. But as I see it, no guidelines or rules were violated.

Comment: @YvetteColomb, well I'm still not convinced and I see that opinions are actually split. I'm a fan of an idea of [evolutionarily stable strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionarily_stable_strategy). IMHO any behavior that will not lead to good results if done by most of the users can not be treated as "good". If everybody made good answers - it would be good for SO. If everybody edited bad questions to improve them - it would be good. If everybody created such a bounty - we would die in noise. And I still see no proofs that this helps search (no I don't see it in the linked data).

Comment: @SergGr that's not going to happen, so don't speak in hypotheticals. SO wants and needs search engine results or it won't exist. To criticise someone wanting to get a decent post onto the google search results is short sighted, particularly when you're saying what is good for the site. As for the meta vote being split, I take that with a grain of salt, as there's a lot of back biting here, that needs to stop and people vote on personality.  There's petty squabbles with users who frequent the same tags as well as on here on meta and that needs to stop. They've done nothing wrong.

Comment: @YvetteColomb, 1)SO needs search results but do you have proofs that this helps? coldspeed linked his proofs but I don't see it there.  Do you see it? (if so, could you point me what convinces you) IMHO good proof would be an answer that was not searchable for like 1 year but after bounty popped up. The linked data can easily be described by organic growth. 2)I don't see why speaking hypothetical is wrong. This trick is not trivial so not many came to that idea but I see no reasons why it 100% will not grow into shameless self-promotion by everyone who can do it as more people learn about it.

Comment: I have no idea if it helps the search results, but that's the reason they're citing in the bounty and it's a good reason. People are inherently reluctant to place bounties for any reason, other than needing the help, as it's hard to make that much rep back from upvotes, so it's a risk @coldspeed is willing to take and it is not doing any harm to the site. Seriously, this is a moot point. I don't know how else to make the connection with you. Oh and did you realise that coldspeed got many downvotes on the main site as a result of the meta effect of this question. Is that good for the site?

Comment: @YvetteColomb, sorry this is not how things work. If I steal things saying that this is good for their health without any proofs that it really is, what I say doesn't matter. What matter is facts. And as I said he did cause harm to the site because he tricked me into opening this question for no good reason. So he stole the time that could be better used to answer some question that needs answering. I bet this bounty in total costs hours of such wasted time among all the people who regularly come here to answer questions. Do you really think it is no harm?

Comment: @SergGr take responsibility for your own post. No one tricked you into opening this post. You posted it, assuming bad faith in another persons actions. Please think about that. Really no one in this world will progress if we don't examine our own mistakes. I make plenty of them. It's not a big deal if you learn from them. So please accept that and do not blame someone else for the indirect harm your actions have caused. It's your post that taken up community time, not the bounties. It's incited ill will and that's not good for the site.

Comment: @YvetteColomb, you misread that. Coldspeed tricked me into openning the first linked question because it appeared as bounty under the `math` tag. And that's why I bet many more people did the same and wasted their time for no good reason. Moreover when I pointed to that, he removed the `math` tag from the question i.e. reduced quality of the question (I reversed it back). And as for downvoted, are you sure they came from meta rather than from the bounty from the same kind of disappointed people as me?

Comment: @SergGr it looks to coincide with this post.

Comment: Anyway, what's done is done. Just think next time what you want to achieve by calling someone out and imagine how you would feel with so many people making critical comments towards you and downvoting your posts. That's all I ask of people, think that at the other end of the keyboard is a person. It was good to meet you. Talk again soon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171402/discussion-between-serggr-and-yvette-colomb).

Comment: [This is a good link to read through in future when dealing with situations like this.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368182/when-and-when-not-to-disclose-names-when-discussing-a-users-actions-on-meta?cb=1) Next time, when discussing the _actions_ of users, please consider _anonymising_ the user. Otherwise, this is nothing but a poorly disguised attack assuming bad intentions. By the way, the reason Yvette  happened across this link is because I flagged Jacob H's comment openly admitting to targeted downvoting as against community guidelines.