# Workaround for minimum bounty for question which you have answered

Tags: discussion, bounty

The page [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) states:

- To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50).

So can I just write an answer, set a bounty, then submit the answer?

(My aim is not to promote my answer, I have an answer which is reasonably good, so I would like to post it but I am still looking for better ones.)

Comment: *So can I just write an answer, set a bounty, then submit the answer?* --> yes you can, what is the problem?

Comment: Seems like it is cheating the system. Maybe I should change "can I" to "should I".

Comment: why it's cheating? In all the case you will be *spending* reputation and you have no way to get it back.

Comment: You should probably not. While it's often possible to cheat the system, it's also a very obvious cheat (and the bounty draws attention, at least, it's intended to). I'm not sure a mod would take action if you do this once, but I wouldn't want to take that chance for 50 rep.

Comment: Alright, thanks, both of you.

Comment: @TemaniAfif There have been incidents/complaints already with people posting _tactical bounties_ to draw upvotes to their answers, and on popular tags they break even or gain reputation even with the required expense of at least 100 rep. If you add bypassing that limit to it, I'm pretty sure it will be an issue.

Comment: @ErikA wouldn't this be a good thing? You bring attention to your answer and if it really deserves upvotes, you will get them. I doubt it will work all the time so it's a *poker game*, you may get you Rep back with upvotes or you may simply loss the Bounty Rep with nothing.

Comment: (My main goal with the bounty is to attract attention to the question, which was posted long time ago by someone else, was not answered - my answer works, but I am pretty sure there is a better one.)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Well, there's some discussion on that, for example [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367891) (Coincidentally, I don't think that question should've been closed). Some users get annoyed by it, because users are drawn to bounties because they want to earn that sweet rep, but can't because there's already an excellent answer the bounty is trying to promote.

Comment: Given that I don't really mind my answer voted down, I decided to [do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60816403/get-week-number-with-week-start-day-different-than-monday-python).

Comment: but you don't know if the your answer will bechossen and second you don't win nothing at all, except there is a bug in the system

Comment: @zabop: At first I thought I had a really clean solution for you but it turned out you asked a different problem that's harder than the one I had a solution for. You got your attention if that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's highlight the part of the rule you're referring to:

> To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question **that you have already *posted* an answer to**, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50).

So, **if you have not already *posted* an answer, then this rule does not apply.**

So, your minimum spend will be 50.

This is not changed if you later post an answer (irrespective of when you drafted its content).

As for whether this is ethical or not, given your intention to do it "deliberately"… I suppose technically not, but it doesn't really matter, does it? It's still your own reputation you're spending. If you routinely abuse bounties to promote your own posts, you may fall foul of the moderators, but I imagine you'd have to be a pretty big nuisance to trigger that.

Comment: "bounties to promote your own posts" - isn't that the whole idea of bounties? How would it ever be "abuse"? Besides that, I don't think one would get the rep back.

Comment: @ThomasWeller most people use bounties to encoourage answers to their question rather than to say "here's an awesome answer that I posted". It kind of feels slightly different to me. Although the fact that you're allowed to use bounties to reward a good existing answer suggests my feelings might be wrong here. Part of the problem with bounties is that you often do get the reputation back (at least on questions), even for fairly poor questions.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Bounties for promoting _questions_ are fine, but bounties for promoting your own _answer_ is a bit of a grey area.

Comment: I had to lookup what "come a cropper" means (I learn something new every day on meta). Now that I've done that I can say... that's an odd usage of "come a cropper".

Comment: @Gimby Heh, looks like I've been misusing that idiom my entire life  Thanks