# Sort answers by most reputed user's answer first

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, sorting

Many a time I found that "users with more reputation" has given better answers than the highest voted answer for the question. Is it possible to add a sorting option for the answers with most reputed user first?

References:

1. [Good late answers don't get enough attention (vote sorting algorithm)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260888/good-late-answers-dont-get-enough-attention-vote-sorting-algorithm?rq=1)
2. [Feature request: introduce an optional sort option for answers that lets new *good* answers rise faster to the top](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294637/feature-request-introduce-an-optional-sort-option-for-answers-that-lets-new-go?rq=1)

**UPDATE**

Answers and comments here say that the name of the user who posted an answer (and so his reputation) is "irrelevant". "We focus on the answer content." If it is so, why tag the author name with the post at all? Why don't we hide the author name from the answer?

Comment: You can safely assume that this will never happen.

Comment: The focus here is on *content*, not users, so the reputation of the user who posted a particular answer is a nigh-irrelevant metric.

Comment: I have found more likely that answers with the highest score are better. So I say let us focus on content here, not the people behind the content.

Comment: *I found that "users with more reputation" has given better answers than the highest voted answer for the question.* Is this a situation where someone has posted a new, updated answer to an old question? Sorting by 'active' should help you find answers like that.

Comment: OK, based on your edit this is about new good answers to old questions. That doesn't have anything to do with reputation. If a 1 rep user posts a new, useful solution to an old question, sorting by rep doesn't help you find it.

Comment: If I were the OP, I would have followed-up with: "well, if that is all true (really?) then what is the point of tagging the post with the author's name?"

Comment: @HansPassant Right on the target

Comment: It is up to you to ask this, I've got entirely too much rep to be able to ask it.  Having too much rep is like having an especially large thyroid gland :)

Comment: This recommendation sounds vaguely of "the rich get richer", only it's with stakes that don't matter that much instead of people's actual livelihoods.

Comment: *why tag the author name with the post at all* Why should we hide it? Why would it be important to prevent someone from seeing a user's other contributions to the site?

Comment: @SandPiper to some degree that is how SO already works. Close threads because they are duplicates of X year old question and make a link to this old question so that the old question gets upvotes. Then there is some that think it's correct to downvote the new thread answers because they didn't know this question (or a similar) was answered X years ago. Oh.. and let's disable the accept button to just in case.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, we focus on the *answer content* here, not the users that wrote them.

What does it matter if the author managed to get a lot of rep elsewhere? They may not even have earned that rep in the current subject. I wouldn't count on me providing quality C# answers, for example.

And if the answers were posted at the same time, then given enough time, the best answer will receive the most votes. If you are worried you might miss out on newer posts, try out the 'active' ordering instead, which will put recently edited (including new) posts up top.

Answer (score 15):

Did you know that [it's possible to score *higher*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10389012/1079354) than [another reputable user's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10389022/1079354), and have your answer be just as good, if not better?

In that vein I see no value in introducing something like this, since it's not *always* the most reputable user that's correct all the time.

Comment: I don't know what metric you're using to say which answer is "better," but Jon's answer is much longer than yours, so it should be ranked higher, imo. ;)

Comment: Love you too @Bill. ;)

Comment: @Lijo:  "Many a time" is the inverse of "not always", so I think we're okay on the semantics here.